# Do Chain Reaction and Infest Broodlings work together?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the Heart of the Swarm campaign, you can give Kerrigan several abilities.

The Chain Reaction ability causes Kerrigan's attacks to bounce to hit up to 5 enemies.

The Infest Broodlings ability causes Kerrigan's attacks to place a temporary debuff on foes, so that they spawn broodlings if they die before it wears off.

If I take both abilities, will all 5 foes hit by Kerrigan's attack receive the Infest Broodlings debuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure does!

I managed to take a screen cap from the start of the Conviction mission:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, they do.** I just finished the campaign yesterday - a lot of fun I might add, and infest broodlings do spawn when together chain reaction. Very useful for taking out groups of marines, or zerglings, or any number of clustered small units.